# How to get current number of connection on a TCP loadbalancer on GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-load-balancer

I have a TCP load balancer on Google cloud, Can I get the active connection count on that load balancer? If yes, how can I get that?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get that information using Cloud Monitoring.

If you have a network TCP Load Balancer [1].

If you have an internal TCP Load Balancer [2].

Example of the metric:

Metric: Open Connections
Name: tcp_ssl_proxy/open_connections
Description: The number of connections open at the given sample moment. Samples are taken one minute apart.

[1] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/tcp/tcp-ssl-proxy-logging-monitoring

[2] https://cloud.google.com/load-balancing/docs/internal/internal-logging-monitoring

Comment: Thanks for your reply. My LB is public. Created by an ingress controller in my k8s cluster.

I found those metrics but unfortunately, they carry no values. I don't know why. I also tried to explore all other metrics related to tcp LB in that place but no data at all!

Comment: Could you explain what you mean when you say "carries no values". Are the monitoring metrics empty? Were you able to configure them?

If the metrics were working but not specifically what you were looking for, you could also create a feature request [1].

[1] https://cloud.google.com/support/docs/issue-trackers